# ubuntu 18.04 how do I install drivers for my NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 After installation, I rebooted the computer, entered the grub menu, pressed e in ubuntu added the nomodeset option and Ubuntu presented the Gnome interface in a resolution of 1024X768 telling me: Unknown Display.
So my question is how to install the drivers for my NVIDIA GTX 1050 graphics card

Comment: @warehouse you can try this link, but I cannot guarantee anything...
[how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux](http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in-linux)

Answer (score 11):

First option is to go into **software and updates**. When you are in **software and updates**, go to the additional drivers page. Wait for a second until it has loaded and see if there are any options there.

The second option is to download it through the terminal. First of all, check the exact graphics card with:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

Find the recommended driver and type the command:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-(driver-number)
```

Or type the command:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```