# NMI Watchdog: BUG: soft lockup with Samsung EVO 970 and Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: kernel, ssd, samsung

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on laptop MSI GP72 7RE - 209XFR with a SSD Samsung 970 EVO.

Ubuntu start and i can go to a console and to the login screen.

On console when i execute :

```
sudo lshw
```

I see the first worf pci but there is nothing else...
After a couple of seconds (ie 25 s) i have the message :

```
NMI Watchdog: BUG: soft lockup ....
```

When i try to login the pc freeze ...

I have the same error on 4.15-29 kernel and 4.17.0-041700 kernel ...

With the previous "standard" sata ssd i have the same trouble for login.  Previously this problem was cause by the presence of nouveau drivers with video card nvidia gtx 1050. I had solved this probleme by the installation of nvidia-driver-391. 
Thus i have installed nvidia-driver-390 driver and after nvidia-driver-396 driver with the Samsung 970 EVO SSD and the problem is still the same ....

How to determine if it's a kernel bug or bios bug or hardware bug ?

Thanks in advance for any help !

Answer (score 0):

It's work with samsung 970 EVO SSD.

The problem is again the nouveau driver for nvidia video card ...

I make a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 with 4.15 kernel. During the installation i have not selected the "install third party ...".

I've made a upgrade of the os (apt-get update & apt-get upgrade) and after :

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
sudo apt install nvidia-(driver-number)

sudo dpkg -l | grep nouveau
```

and i delete (sudo apt-get autoremove ) xorg nouveau driver

[ubuntu 18.04 how do I install drivers for my NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1045241/ubuntu-18-04-how-do-i-install-drivers-for-my-nvidia-geforce-gtx-1050)